# What to use: multiple queue names or multiple routing keys and when?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue

Can anyone explain in which cases I need to create multiple queues (one user -> one queue name), and when one queue name for all clients with different routing keys (one user -> one routing key) and why?

A user should not be able to read messages intended for another user.
I'm using direct exchange type.

Answer (score 0):

First off I am going to assume that when you say "user" you are interchangeably referring to a consumer or producer, and they aren't the same thing so I would read up on that [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) in rabbitmq's simplest explanation.  Walking through that tutorial will definitely help solidify your understanding of rabbit a bit more overall too, which is always good.

In any case, I would recommend doing this:

Create multiple queue's, each one linked to a single consumer.  The reason for doing this instead of using a single queue with multiple is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43884379/in-rabbitmq-which-is-more-expensive-multiple-queues-per-exchange-or-multiple-e) but if you don't want a bunch of programmer jargon, it pretty much says that a single queue is super slow because only one message can be consumed at a time from the queue.

Also, there is a built in "default exchange" that you can use instead of setting up another direct exchange which it sounds like you're putting effort into that you might not need to, obviously I'm not sure what you are doing but I would take that into consideration... hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Yeah, I meant a consumer, of course.