# RabbitMQ Binding Keys - Best Practices

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am binding a queue to a topic exchange with multiple binding keys, and have the following related questions

- Is there a maximum number of binding keys that can be used to bind a single queue to an exchange?
- Is it considered bad practice to use a lot of binding keys for a single queue (say around 50 binding keys)?

I see from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070420/14179842) that "For topic routing, performance decreases as the number of bindings increase".  I am curious to understand a bit more specifically about how drastically performance can decrease, and generally how big the number of bindings can get before it starts affecting performance.